# Find mongodb duplicate field inside of one document

Tags: mongodb

I've got a few bad documents in my database that have a duplicated field, e.g.,

```
{
   _id: ObjectId("5c4b48e317792c00484336cd"),
   updated_at: "2020-03-26 00:00:59.071Z",
   name: "foo",
   name: "foo"
}
```

Also, these are in a database collection with millions of records, although I know the date range these defective ones are in.

What's the best method for locating documents with name listed twice?

Comment: do you want to delete those documents with duplicate values?

Comment: Just identify them

Comment: I managed to solve it by using code with a model that rejects duplicate fields. By catching the exception and binary-searching via date range, I identified the timestamp of the bad document. Still it would be nice to have a proper mongo js solution to this problem.